# How to import a AWS Cognito User Pool in a Flutter Project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

I'm trying to import a existing User Pool to my Amplify Flutter App. I succeeded creating a user pool in amplify CLI as well as creating a authentication in Admin Console sandbox, but I'm getting permissions issues when I perform:

```
amplify auth import

User: arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role/us-east-1_*_Full-access/amplifyadmin is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:ListUserPools on resource: *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant *ListUserPools* permission to role **us-east-1_*_Full-access**, used by amplify to interact with Cognito.

Find **us-east-1_*_Full-access** role in IAM roles and attach a policy with that permission.

=> Replace us-east-1_*_Full-access with the name of the role assumed by Amplify, as shown in the return message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check IAM user permission

Comment: My IAM user has Admin permissions, I think that's not the case because once you are using Amplify, even though you need the IAM keys to access via CLI, you no longer use it, looks like it creates a "unique" IAM, in that case is the "amplifyadmin" specified in the exception above.